# protobuf doesn't see .proto files in gradle project

Tags: gradle, protobuf-java

Protobuf plugin for gradle:

```
id 'com.google.protobuf' version '0.8.13'
```

Here is dependencies from build.gradle

```
implementation "io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:${grpcVersion}"
implementation "io.grpc:grpc-stub:${grpcVersion}"
compileOnly 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2'
implementation "com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:${protobufVersion}"
runtimeOnly "io.grpc:grpc-netty-shaded:${grpcVersion}"
```

I'm trying to start a test in a project. But I get the following error:

```
Could not make proto path relative: D:\Users\�������������\IdeaProjects\service-tester\src\main\proto\messaging_core\message\message.proto: No such file or directory
```

while `message.proto` file is present in the project

[image]

What I need to make protobuf start to see .proto files ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have "protobuf" section in project gradle file? Please take a look at following official example: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/v1.46.x/examples/android/helloworld/app/build.gradle